# Zurb Foundation 6 - Close Modal using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I have a page created using Zurb Foundation 6. I have a modal set up and working correctly.

I am trying to close the modal when an element is clicked like this..

```
jQuery('#test').click(function(){
    jQuery('#exampleModal').foundation('reveal', 'close');
});
```

But this is giving me the following error message...

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: We're sorry, 'reveal' is not an available method for e.
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have too many parameters in the `foundation()` function. Here's the [documentation](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/reveal.html#close) for closing the Reveal modal. Try this:

```
jQuery('#test').click(function() {
    jQuery('#exampleModal').foundation('close');
});
```

Make sure `#test` is the ID of the element you're clicking to close, and `#exampleModal` is the ID of the Reveal modal.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#exampleModal').foundation('close');
```